# How to pass json data via ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am working a visual studio 2012 MVC program.

I use ajax to send data to a controller and wish the controller returns a body of html. the data is in json format. the data is a string name and decimal TotFees.

I found that the parameters value in the public ActionResult ImmPay(string Name) in the controller are always null. Finally I tried just to pass name, but the value of name in the controller side is still null.

what is wrong in my code, and how to solve the problem? Thank you.

```
View:
    function ImmPay()
    {
        var name = "ASP";
        var TotFees = 100.01;       

        //var dd = "{\'name\':\'" + name + "\', \'TotFees\':\'" + TotFees + "\'}"; 
        //var dd = "{\'name\':\'" + name + "\', \'TotFees\':\'" + TotFees + "m\'}";

        dd = "{\'b\':\'" + b + "\'}";
        dd = JSON.stringify(dd);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ImmPay", "Consult")',
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            data: dd,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            context: document.body,
            success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("#dialog-immpay").html(response);
                $("#dialog-immpay").dialog("open");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            },
            complete: function () {
                ;
            }
        });

    }

Controller:
        public ActionResult ImmPay(string Name)
        {
        do something here
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify` takes an object or an array and converts it into JSON, so you can build your data into an object and stringify it like so

```
dd = JSON.stringify({b: b});
```